# In vue-test-utils, how can I pass boolean value to slots option

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-test-utils

Here is my test bootstrap code:

```js
mount(Button, {
  slots: ['<child-component enable="ture" />'],
})
```

the `enable` prop in `child-component` expect a boolean value, but when I try to pass boolean value to this component, it tell me:

> [Vue warn] Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "enable". Expected Boolean, got String with value "false"

So how can I pass boolean value to slots?

Comment: `:enable="true"` as always?